# splitting a string on multiple delimiters

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of chemical reactions in a pandas dataframe that I would like to split into their constituents. The equations are not that complicated, here are a couple of example:

```
N2 + CH4 → HCN + NH3

H2+F2→2HF
```

The goal is to split the string on + and → and get the following

```
['N2','CH4','HCN','NH3]
[H2,'F2','HF']
```

Here is what I have so far

```
import re

df = pd.read_csv("foo.csv") # read the csv file

convert=df['Reaction'].to_string() # convert the reaction column to a string object

result = re.split(r'(\+ →)',convert) # attempt to split on the two delimiters

# alternatively I have tried replacing the right arrow with its unicode equivalent like this

# result = re.split(r'\+\u2192)',convert)
```

Every time I run this code, i get back the same exact string with no changes.

I have also attempted to keep the column as a list object instead of a string object and then

tried to split it, when I do that I get `Type Error: Expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: You could use a character class instead `[+ →]+` See https://ideone.com/xKRi3c

Comment: You may be able to split on `\W+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you work with a dataframe, there's the pandas method `Series.str.split`. And we can split on multiple characters. Only in this case we have whitespaces in some cases, so we have take that into account as well.

```
df['Reaction_new'] = df['Reaction'].str.split('\s?[+→]\s?')
```

Or as mentioned in the comments by [`ctwheels`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59505025/splitting-a-string-on-multiple-delimiters/59505095#comment105182470_59505025), simply:

```
df['Reaction_new'] = df['Reaction'].str.split('\W+')
```

```
               Reaction         Reaction_new
0  N2 + CH4 → HCN + NH3  [N2, CH4, HCN, NH3]
1             H2+F2→2HF        [H2, F2, 2HF]
```

Comment: I would change your first regex to simply `\s?[+→]\s?` (zero or one space) or `\s*[+→]\s*` (any number of spaces)

Comment: Good point, thanks. @ctwheels

Answer (score 2):

You're splitting on the literal string `+ →`, but that never appears in your data.

You can use `[]` to match any of multiple characters.

```
result = re.split(r'\s*[+→]\s*',convert)
```

Also, you shouldn't put a capture group around the delimiter regexp, as that will cause the delimiters to be included in the results.